# google place api Incorrect Results

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-api-php-client

Hi I have a problem with displaying the results of a google place api 
When I write nightclub Google search I get results that match my search 
But when I search through google place api I get the results is not so correct as Bookstore, apartments for rent and other results not so related 
The URL looks like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.0768214,34.8147987&radius=5000&keyword=Nightclub&sensor=true&language=en&key=MyKey
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs state](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests):

> keyword — A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this Place, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content.

So that filter isn't going to be quite as specific as you would like.  If you only want to get night clubs, you can use the `types` param with a value of `night_club`.  See [Supported Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) for all of the other possible values.

Comment: This is just an example, 
The Place Types very limited and so helpful